# Create Map out of JSON

Tags: java, json

I am writing an application in Java which deals with stock values.
I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{
"Meta Data": 
{
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices ,
    "2. Symbol": "FB",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-04-21 10:24:00",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2017-04-21 10:24:00": {
        "1. open": "143.9000",
        "2. high": "144.1700",
        "3. low": "143.4600",
        "4. close": "143.7800",
        "5. volume": "2784942"
    },
    "2017-04-20": {
        "1. open": "142.9500",
        "2. high": "144.2500",
        "3. low": "142.6900",
        "4. close": "143.8000",
        "5. volume": "15917800"
    },
    "2017-04-19": {
        "1. open": "141.3500",
        "2. high": "143.0400",
        "3. low": "141.2700",
        "4. close": "142.2700",
        "5. volume": "15500400"
    },
    "2017-04-18": {
        "1. open": "141.2700",
        "2. high": "141.9100",
        "3. low": "140.6100",
        "4. close": "140.9600",
        "5. volume": "14790800"
    }
  }
}
```

I can get list of stock values using GSON but then as JSON is unsorted I don't really know the date of specific stock value.

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final List<String> stockValues = gson.fromJson(JSON2, JsonElement.class)
            .getAsJsonObject()
            .get("Time Series (Daily)") // get the divisions property
            .getAsJsonObject()
            .entrySet() // and traverse its key/value pairs
            .stream()
            .map(Entry::getValue) // discarding the keys
            .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonObject)
            .map(jo -> jo.get("1. open")) // take the id property from the every `division` object
            .map(JsonElement::getAsJsonPrimitive)
            .map(JsonPrimitive::getAsString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I would really need is to make a Map which contains pairs of **date** and **stock value ("open")**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is a " missing after "1. Information": "Daily Prices",. The solution is

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new File("path_to_json_file"));
    JsonNode data = node.get("Time Series (Daily)");

    Iterator<String> iterator = data.fieldNames();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String date = iterator.next();
        JsonNode value = data.get(date);

        Map<String, Double> priceMap = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<String> itr = value.fieldNames();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String param = itr.next();
            JsonNode price = value.get(param);

            priceMap.put(param.replaceAll(" ", "").split("\\.")[1], price.asDouble());
        }
        map.put(date, priceMap);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

The output: {2017-04-18={volume=1.47908E7, high=141.91, low=140.61, close=140.96, open=141.27}, 2017-04-21 10:24:00={volume=2784942.0, high=144.17, low=143.46, close=143.78, open=143.9}, 2017-04-20={volume=1.59178E7, high=144.25, low=142.69, close=143.8, open=142.95}, 2017-04-19={volume=1.55004E7, high=143.04, low=141.27, close=142.27, open=141.35}}